# How to add activity indicator to the image in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, uiactivityindicatorview

I have created the Custom `tableView` and using custom `tableView` class in Other class to Show the `tableView`..

I am Loading the image from Server and displaying it in the `tableViewRow`.. each `image` is different in it..

On Screen only 7 out of 10 images will come, and when I scroll down the first 3 images are repeating for some time and when those images get load its showing proper images.. but initially till new images will come its showing old images, I want to put a activity indicator to show that the images are loading instead of old images..

I want to add `activity Indicator` in the place of `image`, till the `image` get load..

My code is...

```
self.tableViewX = tableView;
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
    {
NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"www.xyz.image.png"];
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
 });
```

Please assist me with some sample code..

Comment: You can use asynchronous image view  to achieve this .Because the image is showin like that as  You are using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier so  make a diferent idefier or make cell is nill.. then u can achieve it

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: @08442 : How to use asynchronous image view? do you have any sample code from which i can understand it..

Comment: @bhargavi: do we need ASIHTTPRequest class to do this?

Comment: Cant i create the subView of image so that the activity indicator will work till the image is loaded?

Comment: @Raju yes you need ASIHTTPRequest for async imageview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "AsyncImageView" class files it will load image synchronically and it shows the activity indicator while image loading

You can download "AsyncImageView" class files from following link:-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/peazwjvky9fsjd7/Archive.zip

in .m file import AsyncImageView Class

```
 #import "AsyncImageView.h"
```

in your tableview cell at indexpath method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
     SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil)
     {
           NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     }
     NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"www.xyz.image.png"];
     AsyncImageView *async = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
     [async loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
     [cell.thumbnailImageView addSubview:async];
}
```

try this your problem will solve.

Comment: what will this "[async loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strThumbImageUrl] imageName:@""];" statement will do? and what is strThumbImageUrl? is it same as imageURL?

Comment: this is your image url please check answer now i have edit the answer

Comment: its showing the error "No visible @interface for 'AsyncImageView' declares the selector 'loadImageFromURL:imageName:'"

Comment: this is asyncImageView class files method
remove imagename:@"" and try 
look i have edit the code

Comment: i also tried "[async loadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]" but its still showing  "No visible @interface for 'AsyncImageView' declares the selector 'loadImageWithURL:'" error..

Comment: please use below another class files download it from below link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/peazwjvky9fsjd7/Archive.zip

Comment: @Raju Try changing the `loadImageFromURL` to `loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url` as the interface has this method in it:- `- (void)loadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL;`.

Comment: @Pratik Edit your answer to match the method name. Make it `loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)`.

Comment: how can i add the image from the system to this async class? i have one image in supported files.. how can i load this image to async class?

Comment: @zen: i have tried that also..   " loadImageFromURL to loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url as the interface has this method in it:- - (void)loadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL;"   but that was showing some error..

Comment: @Raju What is that error. And for loading local images, Check the demo out. He loads images from both local and online resources. Go through that.

Comment: @zen :error was "'AsyncImageView' declares the selector 'loadImageWithURL:'"

Comment: actually i got the solution.. but when i am not getting how to load the local image to same async class.. and when i am trying "cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageLock.png"];" its getting struck some times..

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView Did you download this from here. You can see the demo code in it.

Comment: I am doing it like this and its getting struck at some places.. "if ([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]] == nil)
        {
            AsyncImageView *async = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            NSString *lockImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageLock" ofType:@"png"];
            [async loadImageFromURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:lockImage]];
            [cell.thumbnailImageView addSubview:async];
        } else { image From Server }