# How to make SDWebImage maintain size in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

cell.imageView is displayed correctly on first loading.
After the UITableViewCell move off screen and back on again, suddenly cell.imageView size has changed to fill the height of the cell.
Same thing when the cell set to highlighted state.
cell.imageView is created in interface builder.

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSDictionary *dataType = [self.dataTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dataType valueForKey:@"imageURL"]]
                   placeholderImage:nil];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [data valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [data valueForKey:@"info"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What does `prepareForReuse` look like in your `CustomCell` class?

Comment: why you use CustomCell instead of UITableViewCell?

Comment: @MishieMoo I'm nor overriding 'prepareForReuse'  , should I be?

Comment: @Pratik I'm using a custom cell that I've laid out in interface builder that is of CustomCell class. It's just a simple subclass of UITableViewCell, it's only real purpose is so I can access IBOutlets for it's subviews.

Comment: look my answer and let me know is it worked for you or not? if not then i will suggest other solution.

Answer (score 0):

try below answer and do needful changes in it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331306/1713478

in this answer add

```
cell.titleLabel.text = [data valueForKey:@"name"];
cell.descriptionLabel.text = [data valueForKey:@"info"];
```

and just change **SimpleTableCell** with **CustomCell** and in **imageURL** put your image URL

and do other needful changes.

may be your problem will solve.

Comment: This is a workaround and it works but I was hoping to get to the bottom of SDWebimage and why it's behaving like that.

Comment: I can't understand what you want to tell.

Comment: The question was why is SDWebimage doing what it's doing. Suggesting to use something else is helpful but not a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well inspired by Pratik's answer I decided to remove the UIImageView from interface builder and create it on the fly. This works as expected but I'm not sure why it's any different. Possibly something to do with the IB constraints.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSDictionary *data = [self.dataTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImageView *thumb = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 10, 52, 74)];
    [thumb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[data valueForKey:@"imageURL"]]
                   placeholderImage:nil];
    [cell addSubview:thumb];
    [thumb release];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [data valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [data valueForKey:@"info"];

    return cell;
}
```