# Table view scroll lagging when using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I am loading some images from the internet in a table view inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    Article *article = [parser items][indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = article.title;
    cell.newsDescription.text = article.description;
    [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:article.image]];

    return cell;
}
```

My problem is that even if I use `SDWebImage`, when I scroll down, my app still lags. Here is some screenshots from `Instruments`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How big are the images?

Comment: well, something between 50.000 and 200.000, lets say 150 KB

Comment: What type are the images? TIFF?

Comment: You solved this problem?

Comment: @Nikita: my problem was that I was doing more work to the image after downloading it on the main thread (making the picture round), does the accepted answer works for you ?

Comment: @vBx, i have already realized that this is due to the very large images. Thanks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like even though the download of the image is performed in a background thread, the work with the image data is done in the main thread, thus it blocks your application. You could try the asynchronous image downloader provided by SDWebImage.

```
[SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                                    options:0
                                                   progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize)
                                                   {
                                                       // progression tracking code
                                                   }
                                                   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
                                                   {
                                                       if (image && finished)
                                                       {
                                                           // do something with image
                                                       }
                                                   }
];
```

In your method it should look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    Article *article = [parser items][indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = article.title;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.newsDescription.text = article.description;
    [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                                                        options:0
                                                       progress:nil
                                                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
     {
         if (cell.tag == indexPath.row && image && finished)
         {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
               cell.image = image;
            });

         }
     }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: 1) It not tracking the imageview so not putting the images on correct imageviews on scrolling.
2) Images get off on scrolling and shows up after sometime again.
Seems not using Cache

Comment: About number 2, SDWebImageDownloader caches images by default.

Comment: Yes but images should not placed incorrectly even if they are coming from cache! Check your code by your self! 2) issue is still there!

Answer (score 1):

Download the image on a separate thread, like so:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL];
                        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                            if ( data )
                            {
                                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                [cell.image setImage:image];
                            }
                        }];
```

Comment: @vBx said he already uses the sdWebImage extension which uses a seperated thread.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has less to do with network activity and more to do with your image sizes. Resizing images, especially for non-integer multipliers, is expensive. If your images are significantly larger than the view you are putting them into, you need to resize and cache them in a background thread, and reference the cached copy from your view.

To confirm if this is your issue, manually download all the images and reference the local copy. If I am correct, your UITableView will still lag the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load asynchronously from server so your tableView will scrolling smoothly.

Please check below answer you will be able to solve your problem.

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331306/1713478**

Answer (score 0):

Check you images, check the types and size and more important: Is one or more image broken by its file format in any way? Filesize too big, irregular (to large) bounds?

Try to open and re-save suspiciously image files with an image editor, to be sure the internal file format is OK.